# App works in Flash Pro but not on the web

Tags: php, database, actionscript-3, flash, amfphp

Ok, so I'm having this problem with an application I wrote in AS3 and PHP (Linked together using AMFPHP) and What happens is (Using a basic way of saying it) I retrieve data from a database and display it on the screen. I've done this many times before and it works on both the web and in Flash Pro. itself. The problem I'm having this time is that it works perfectly in Flash Pro. but when I upload it to my web host, it doesn't work and it shows a blank screen. Any suggestions? If you require any additional information please ask :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the most recent crossdomain policy attached to the domain serving the data?

Comment: A Cross Domain Isn't Required As The .swf and the data is on the same domain.

Comment: send me the link to website, i could check it for you quickly...